# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException. What is the cause?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm quite new to Laravel and I'm facing a vague error. Whenever I try to login with an username and password, I get this error.

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

My code consists of this:

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function postSignUp(Request $request){
        $firstName = $request['firstName'];
        $lastName = $request['lastName'];
        $username = $request['username'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);
        $email = $request['email'];

        $user = new User();
        $user->first_name = $firstName;
        $user->last_name = $lastName;
        $user->username = $username;
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->email = $email;

        $user->save();

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function postSignIn(Request $request){
        $username = $request['username'];
        $password = $request['password'];
        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])){
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
}
```

Provider called User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
}
```

Route file web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('signup', 'UserController@postSignUp')->name('signup');
Route::get('signin', 'UserController@postSignin')->name('signin');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.5 error when try to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058746/laravel-5-5-error-when-try-to-login)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MethodNotAllowed means that you are using a VERB that the webserver didn't like for that request... i.e. GET instead of POST.

Your controller for sign-in is called `postSignIn` but I notice that you are calling it with a `get`

Answer (score 0):

It’s because the route doesn’t exist. Add the sign in post route. postSignin should be a post route

```
Route::post('signin', 'UserController@postSignin')->name('signin');

Route::get('signin', 'UserController@getSignin')->name('signInForm');
```

Instead of

```
Route::get('signin', 'UserController@postSignin')->name('signin’);
```